# Probability: discarding things without knowing their identities

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

You have a bag of 4 white chips and 6 red chips. Two chips are drawn and discarded, without you knowing the identities of the chips. What is the probability that the third chip drawn is red?

I am aware of a short cut to this and that the solution is the same as drawing the first chip as red. This means that the result is 0.6.

I have tried to work it out using tedious conditional probability. Is there a theorem that generalises this statement?

Answer (score 1):

Using the Law of Total Probabilities will be tedious.  Well, not too tedious for this, but it can get worse the longer the list.

Letting $R_1,R_2,R_3$ be the events for drawing red on draw $1,2,3$, respectively, and likewise $W_1,W_2,W_3$ be their complements (aka drawing white on the relevant draws).

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(R_3)&=\mathsf P(R_1,R_2,R_3)+\mathsf P(W_1,R_2,R_3)+\mathsf P(R_1,W_2,R_3)+\mathsf P(W_1,W_2,R_3)\\&=\dfrac 6{10}\dfrac 5{9}\dfrac 4{8}+\dfrac 4{10}\dfrac 6{9}\dfrac 5{8}+\dfrac 6{10}\dfrac 4{9}\dfrac 5{8}+\dfrac 4{10}\dfrac 3{9}\dfrac 6{8}\\&=\dfrac{6}{10}\dfrac{4\cdot(5\cdot 3+ 3)}{9\cdot 8}\\&=\dfrac{6}{10}\end{align}$$

That is why it is nice to be able to **reason from first principles**: "Each of the ten balls has *an unbiased chance* to be drawn third, and six of the ten are red.  Therefore the probability that the third drawn ball will be red is $6/10$."

That's not a theorem, it is just modelling this particular system.

---

Still, it is nice to see that the two approaches are consilient.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call it a *theorem,* perhaps but consider this:

**With no a priori information**, *the probability that a particular type of object occupies a* **particular** *position in a sequence is equal to the probability that it occupies* **any** *position in the sequence.*